# Can't figure out how to determine if a SimpleXML node is empty

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So I have this code:

```
foreach ($xml->PrintQuestion as $PrintQuestion) {

     //if hint doesn't exist, store question id
     if (!$PrintQuestion->content->multichoice->feedback->hint->Passage) {

         fwrite($fp, "<contentid filename=\"$value\">" . $PrintQuestion->attributes()->id . "</contentid>");

     }

}
```

Basically, I'm trying to save IDs to an XML file if the `Passage` node exists, but it seems to be storing every ID whether nodes exist within `Passage` or not.

Comment: What datatype is `Passage`?  Is SimpleXML converting it to an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if you use `empty()`

```
if( empty($PrintQuestion->content->multichoice->feedback->hint->Passage) ) {

    fwrite($fp, "<contentid filename=\"$value\">" . $PrintQuestion->attributes()->id . "</contentid>");      

}
```

Comment: `empty` doesnt work with attributes. If the node `$currentService->HotelInfo->Destination` is null, this instructions rises an error:  `if (!empty($currentService->HotelInfo->Destination->attributes ()->code ))`

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the value as a string and compare to an empty string (sort of like [how to check a value of simplexml object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074256/how-to-check-a-value-of-simplexml-object)):

```
$value = $root->child;

if ((string)$value === '') {
  echo 'This passes if the child element existed, but was empty';
}
```