# how to check a value of simplexml object

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object, simplexml

i have an array that is simple xml object. i am writing the codes below

```
Array
(
[ID] => 1992109
[Title] => A Equipa do MAIS
[Description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )
 )
```

now how can i check the value of Description in this array that if there is a value of Description is present or not.

Comment: Hint, hint...you need to accept Michael's answer below by clicking the checkmark!

Answer (score 8):

To verify if a `SimpleXMLElement` object has a text value, you'll need to cast it as a string:

```
$desc = (string)$array['Description'];
if (!empty($desc)) {
  echo $desc;
}
```

Although you are able to directly `echo` the contents of a `SimpleXMLElement` object, to use its string value as a variable requires typecasting it.  `empty()` must act on a variable<sup>1</sup>, so the element's implicit `__toString()` call won't work as it does with `echo`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Beginning with PHP 5.5, `empty()` can test an arbitrary expression's result. It no longer requires a variable as its argument.

Comment: Can also use strval($XML->description) when setting it in the array. Will type casting it work once it's already assigned to the array?

Comment: @showerhead The object's behavior and state aren't  affected by its membership in an array. Remember that if you have several similar XML elements, SimpleXML will present them as an array of objects too.